# Getting error SyntaxError: Missing semicolon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, syntax-error, semicolon-inference

Checked the code and cannot find where I need to put a semicolon.
Here is [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsKgq.png).
Here is the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHF6L.png).

Comment: Please include any relevant information (that includes errors and code) in the question itself as text rather than images. That makes it easier for us to copy/paste your code into an editor to try to reproduce/fix the issue, and for others to find this question when they run into the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
const Routes = (props) => ( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

*It should be like this*

```
const PropsPage = () => {  return (    <h3>Props Page</h3>  );};
```

for a

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <section className="App">
      <Router>
        ...
        <Link to="/404-not-found">404</Link>
        <Link to="/props">Passing Props</Link>        <Switch>
          ...
          <Route exact path="/props" component={PropsPage} />          <Route component={NoMatchPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <a href="/about">about with browser reload</a>
    </section>
  );
};
```

*Passing function as a component props in Route component*

```
const PropsPage = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <h3>{title}</h3>
  );
};
```